# Web based document editor

Tags: web-apps, html-editor, wysiwyg, word-processor

I want a web based document editor, I'm using CKEditor.

This might be duplicate question of [Open source, web-based document editor?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/open-source-web-based-document-editor)

But I want some more powerful editing options like MS Word/OpenOffice gives. Like I want...

- Breaks like Page break, Section break etc.
- Page setup like page orientation, page size etc.
- Page level formating like watermark, page borders etc.
- Very good level of table formatting like in MS Word and MS Excel.
- Plugin development as content can be dynamically generated as per logic.
- Output should be in open xml standard

**Note: Editor must be based on web and must not on cloud.**

Comment: based on web and must not on cloud: Could you clarify what you mean? For instance, should it be able to work when offline?

Comment: Maybe you should include the Open XML requirement into the question title, because most programs mentioned in that other post will not do that.

Comment: Could you describe what problem you want to solve? That way we have some context to see if something we know applies to it. Also do you want to host the web-app on one of your servers (intranet style) or do you want to have some web-app thats hosted somewhere else? If the latter, why not cloud based systems?

Comment: I want open editor in web browser but my application is not based on cloud. So I want an editor which runs in web browser but on cloud like Google Docs or Office 365.

Comment: @Mitesh Your Question is not clear. You've not yet responded to the comments’ questions. You’ve not explained how open-source is relevant. You’ve not explained what "based on web and must not on cloud" means.