# Web-based Text Editor for Server Files

Tags: web-apps, web-development, text-editor

I have a list of files on my development server that I want users (who are already authenticated against the webserver) to be able to edit. I don't want to bother them with FTP or WebDAV, so I would like them to go to a URL, pick the file to edit from a menu and edit it in the browser.

The files include plain text files, configuration files, HTML, JavaScript or CSS, so syntax-highlighting, code-folding etc. would be nice. But I am looking for a plain text editor, not WYSIWYG as I think it would be a distraction.

None of my Google searches returned anything interesting due to the keywords being so common on the Internet. Does anyone know an (open-sourced) editor that I could use for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source, web-based document editor?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/open-source-web-based-document-editor)

Comment: @JanDoggen Not sure this is an exact duplicate. The question you've linked e.g. has no requirements for syntax highlighting, code folding, etc. This here is rather the "developers version" – while your link is the "end-user version". Closely related, but no duplicate IMHO. Additionally, the other question explicitely requires WYSIWYG – while Twinkles explicitly wants that ruled out.

Comment: Comment, rather than answer, as this is just a link/pointer - does [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) hold any possibilities? Similar, Eclipse's [Orion](https://orionhub.org/mixloginstatic/landing.html?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Forionhub.org%2F&key=FORMOAuthUser).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at "web/hosting" control panels. For example, Webmin's file manager plugin supports editing text files, "http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/File_Manager". There are a wide variety of such control panels (EG Ajenti or cPanel), and they can be used to manage as much or as little on your server as you like.

Note: this is written to the assumption that you want to edit files that 'live' on the server. Which is different from the question linked in the earlier comment.

Comment: The Webmin File Manager seems to only allow creating/deleting files, not editing them and via cPanel I can edit *any* file, which is presumably too much power. But thanks for pointing me in the general direction of a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at low or no cost packages like

[ShiftEdit](https://shiftedit.net/) Easy to connect to any server. Monthly cost for more than one project / user.

or

[Koding](https://koding.com/) is great for hosting, sharing and testing data but was a bit complicated for me to learn.

Basically, you setup the system to connect to your server, add authorized users and folders, train them then adjust your settings based on what your users teach you.

I have used both.

Comment: Do you have experience with either one, and are there any aspects that you liked or disliked?

Comment: I have used both.  ShiftEdit is easier to connect to any server but it costs for more than one user.  Koding is great for hosting and testing the data but can be complicated to learn.

Comment: Great! Could you [edit] that into your answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution webadmin lite,Webmin es un panel de control web moderno que le permite administrar su servidor Linux a través de una interfaz basada en navegador. Con Webmin, puede administrar cuentas de usuario, configurar los ajustes de DNS, y cambiar la configuración para los paquetes comunes en el momento.

[image]

Comment: Welcome Jairo! Thank you for your contribution. For better or worse, all contributions in this site must be in the English language.  If you will translate your answer to English, we can keep your helpful contribution.  Thanks, and again, welcome!